# How to Iterate Json response data in Angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I m getting this json data as a response and i m trying to iterate this data inside "component template attribute" to show the content in "li" tag html

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "aliases": [
        "http://www.xyz.co",
        "http://facebook.xyz.co"
      ],
      "styling": {
        "tag_background_color": "#E0EAF1",
        "tag_foreground_color": "#3E6D8E",
        "link_color": "#0077CC"
      },
      "related_sites": [
        {
          "relation": "meta",
          "api_site_parameter": "meta.xyz",
          "site_url": "http://meta.xyz.co",
          "name": "Meta Stack Overflow"
        },
        {
          "relation": "chat",
          "site_url": "http://chat.xyz.co",
          "name": "Stack Overflow Chat"
        }
      ],
      "markdown_extensions": [
        "Prettify"
      ],
      "launch_date": 1221436800,
      "closed_beta_date": 1217462400,
      "site_state": "normal",
      "high_resolution_icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/sxyz/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png",
      "favicon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico",
      "icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/xyz/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
      "audience": "professional and enthusiast programmers",
      "site_url": "http://xyz.co",
      "api_site_parameter": "xyz",
      "logo_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/logo.png",
      "name": "Stack Overflow",
      "site_type": "main_site"
    },
    {
      "aliases": [
        "http://www.xyz.co",
        "http://facebook.xyzw.co"
      ],
      "styling": {
        "tag_background_color": "#E0EAF1",
        "tag_foreground_color": "#3E6D8E",
        "link_color": "#0077CC"
      },
      "related_sites": [
        {
          "relation": "meta",
          "api_site_parameter": "meta.xyz",
          "site_url": "http://meta.xyz.co",
          "name": "Meta Stack Overflow"
        },
        {
          "relation": "chat",
          "site_url": "http://chat.xyz",
          "name": "Stack Overflow Chat"
        }
      ],
      "markdown_extensions": [
        "Prettify"
      ],
      "launch_date": 1221436800,
      "closed_beta_date": 1217462400,
      "site_state": "normal",
      "high_resolution_icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/xyz/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png",
      "favicon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/sxyz/img/favicon.ico",
      "icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/xyz/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
      "audience": "professional and enthusiast programmers",
      "site_url": "http://stackoverflow.co",
      "api_site_parameter": "stackoverflow",
      "logo_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/xyzw/img/logo.png",
      "name": "Stack Overflow",
      "site_type": "main_site"
    }
  ]
}
```

my js code is shown below

```
@Component({
    selector: 'http-test',
    template: ` 
       <ul>    
          <li *ngFor="#data of httpData>{{data.items.related_sites[0].name}}  //trying to iterate the response data.
          </li>
       </ul>
     `,
     providers:[HTTPTestService]

})


export class HTTPTestComponent {
    public httpData;

    constructor (private _httpService: HTTPTestService){}

    getStack(){
      this._httpService.getItemData()
          .subscribe(             
             data =>this.httpData = JSON.stringify(data),
             error => alert(error),
             () =>console.log("finished")
          );
    }
    ngOnInit() {
      this.getStack();
    }
 }
```

I ve tried but i can achieve what i want,please help me,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <li *ngFor="let data of httpData.items>{{data.related_sites[0].name}}  //trying to iterate the response data.
  </li>
```

Comment: tried ,getting exception<br> "EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined in [responseData.items in HTTPTestComponent@3:13]"

Comment: data =>{this.httpData = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(this.httpData);},

Comment: i'm also tried, but didn't get answer<br>Following ERROR:<br>EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token ), expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 24 in [ngFor #data of httpData)] in HTTPTestComponent@3:13 ("
       <ul>
         <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="#data of httpData)">{{data}}</li>
       </ul>
     "): HTTPTestComponent@3:13

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li *ngFor="let item of httpData.items>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let alias of item.aliases>
        {{alias}}</br>
      </li>
    </ul> 
    ..
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let related_site of item.related_sites>
        {{relation}}
        {{api_site_parameter}}
        {{site_url}}
        {{name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
     ..
     ..
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see is that in your `getStack()` function, where you subscribe to the http response observer, you convert the response to a `string` by calling `JSON.stringify(data)`. You'd actually need an object instead of it's `JSON` string representation, so you can reference its properties in your template.

You did not post the code for your HTTPTestService class, so we don't know if you do any kind of post-processing - possibly with a `.map(...)` call - on the response before passing it on to the subscriber(s). If you return the original `Observable<Response>` to the subscriber, then you'll need to parse the response body into a valid object. You can do this by replacing the following line

```
data =>this.httpData = JSON.stringify(data)
```

with

```
data => this.httpData = data.json()
```

Please note that it is preferable to place this conversion in your service file, which should already return a valid object to your component. Also make sure that you put the parsing call in a `try-catch` block, in case the server returns an invalid `JSON` response.

Once you fixed the parsing of the http response, you should be able to iterate through your data as outlined by `Amol Bhor` in this [other response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41382223/405481)